# HttpParams dont request filtered JSON

Tags: angular, httpclient, http-parameters

I have a really simple http request.

My Front end:

```
<button mat-button (click)="onSubmit()">Login</button>
```

My onSubmit():

```
onSubmit() {

this.personService.getPersonByName().subscribe(person => {
  console.log('Person', person);
});
```

My PersonService getPersonByName():

```
  private personURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/persons'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getPersonByName(): Observable<Person> {

     let params = new HttpParams().set('username', 'SwaX');

     return this.http.get<Person>(this.personURL, { params });
 }
```

What i get:

[image]

Why do i get 3 Objects instead of 1?

Comment: Show your backend. What is it expecting as params?

Comment: The request is working. The Filtering through the "param" HttpParam object doesn't work.

Comment: I just want to know your backend expects id or username

Comment: you have tested request with another app like Postman? It works?

Comment: I am going to try it with Postman. Loopback tells me "Server response 200" and i get the person Objects.

Comment: Postman gives me also the respons i expect.

Comment: Show postman URL that you have tested

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/persons

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your API, not Angular. You're not filtering down your response before sending it back over the wire. You could fix it on the API side and have it return a single object instead of an array of objects or you could filter the object out of the response in your service's getPersonByName() method using map -

```
getPersonByName(username: string): Observable<Person> {
    return this.http.get<Person[]>(this.personURL)
        .pipe(
           .map(people => people.find(person => person.username === username)
        );
}
```

Comment: When i try to use find() i get "Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Person'."
What should i do?

Comment: I was missing a .pipe() in there. Give it a try with the map method wrapped in pipe as shown in the edited snippet above.

Comment: Honestly though I would go with what others are saying and get your API to return the specific object instead of filtering it out from a list. It's cleaner to get exactly what you need from the API instead of sifting through a bunch of data on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return this.http.get<Person>(`${this.personURL}?username=SwaX`);
```

or,

```
return this.http.get<Person>(`${this.personURL}/1`);
```

based on your backend param

Comment: i still get 3 objects

Comment: i try to filter this URL : http://localhost:3000/api/persons/ to only 1 object.
Is that the wrong way of thinking?
Because i just saw that loopback prepared this URL for me : GET /persons/{id}
And i tried it like that :http://localhost:3000/api/persons/1
That works. So do i have to change something in the API ?

Comment: Try `this.http.get<Person>(`${this.personURL}/1`);`

Comment: i tried this `return this.http.get<Person>(this.personURL + '/1');`
And i only got 1. But it is filtered by the id not the name.

Comment: For that, your backend should have an endpoint that accepts username> Do your backend have it?

Comment: ok i get it i try to get into endpoints and learn more about that thank you. Now i know what to do. Because i have no knowledge what so ever about endpoints. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing something small, and it's that the HttpParams in the request would be mapped to join the URL. Then doing

```
getPersonByName(): Observable<Person> {
   let params = new HttpParams().set('username', 'SwaX');
   return this.http.get<Person>(this.personURL, { params });
}
```

is similar to doing

```
getPersonByName(): Observable<Person> {
   return this.http.get<Person>(this.personURL + '?username=Swax');
}
```

Which should produce the same results. As it's a `GET`request, so you can also test it using your browser. Simply open

`http://localhost:3000/api/persons?username=Swax`

in your browser and see what comes. This way you'll be able to determine if the problem comes from your API or not.